# Is it possible to obtain ice in superflat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to use silk touch on ice generated from Frost walker boots, but ran into the realization that it is not possible to obtain ice like that. Is there another possiblility to achive ice in superflat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your world isn't in either a cold biome, or extreme hills biome, then you can only obtain packed and blue ice as trades from the wandering trader and normal ice is unobtainable.

Additionally, frosted ice never melts in low light levels, so it's possible to generate it where you need it. This was used, for example, for building [ice highways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvONs8Tov9Q).